# Would you please show me how to use"it"?

Tags: pronouns

A. We cannot consider worthless people who...

B. It cannot be considered worthless people who...

C. People who... cannot be considered worthless.

I would like to say the sentences like A.
My biggest problem is due to B, as I wonder if it is correct.

Any comment would be appreciated

Comment: You need a pause after "worthless" in A and B.  I suggest using "the" with 'people': "*We cannot consider worthless **the** people who*..."  And 'B' starts wrong.  "People" are not "it".

Comment: Thank you so much. So, how could we say B with"it" as an impersonalized refrence ?

Comment: I can't think of any way to say it besides something like "It would be a mistake to consider worthless the people who..."

Comment: @Victor: The obvious way is OP's example #C, where the significant adjective *(worthless)* appears in its natural position at the *end* of the statement. People are just being clumsy who use OP's format #A - it's much more idiomatic to say people who use OP's format #A are just being clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a more complete context to examine this usage in detail, so let's look at...

> 1: *We cannot consider worthless people who get drunk on New Year's Eve.*

...which has two different possible meanings...

> 1a: *We cannot consider [**as**] worthless **those** people who get drunk on New Year's Eve.*
>    (They are not worthless, and we should not label them as such.)
>
> 1b: *We cannot consider **those** worthless people who get drunk on New Year's Eve.*
>    (They *are* worthless, and we should not take them into account in our present deliberations.)

In *speech*, sense 1a would normally be unambiguously conveyed by stressing the word ***worthless***, but italicizing it in the written form wouldn't necessarily have the same effect anyway. That's because there are two potential "sub-nuances"...

> 1a1: ...***worthless*** isn't the best possible word here (following text may suggest better alternatives).
>    1b1: ...*[they are not] **worthless*** is a simple refutation *(they do have some merit)*.

Partly because of these potential semantic ambiguities, OP's example A is thus at least "problematic" in the written form (plus it's a somewhat stylized/stilted word order). B is simply ungrammatical. But C is perfectly natural and unambiguous.

---

The only way I can think of to introduce "existential **it**" in OP's context would be something like...

> 2: ***It*** would be wrong to consider people who get drunk on New Year's Eve [as / to be] worthless.

That's to say **it** references either the specific action *consider people who [blah blah]* OR *"judgement" as a general concept*. It can't be used in such contexts to directly refer to the [worthless] people themselves.

Comment: Actually *worthless* will be stressed in both  versions of the sentence. The difference will be that the 1a reading will have two IPs, two complete musical tunes. The first will end on the word *worthless*, the second on *EVE*. In the 1b sentence worthless will appear in the middle of the IP. There will probably be only one IP and it will end on the word *Eve*. So the 1a reading will involve a nuclear syllable on the words *worthless* and *eve*, 1b will just have one on *eve*. But *worthless* will definitely be stressed in both readings.

Comment: @Araucaria: I didn't bother trying to cover exactly how my "sub-nuances" would/could be disambiguated in speech/writing because it was straying too far from OP's central issue concerning "existential it". But I agree both involve placing stress on *worthless*. In speech, #1b1 would be "light" stress (just enough to steer the audience away from what might otherwise be the more likely interpretation #1b above). But the #1a1 sense would have *heavy* stress (which I might feasibly represent in writing by enclosing "**worthless**" in scare quotes).